# Text left align issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using remodal.js (https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal) to create a modal: http://jsfiddle.net/j4wnov5z/.

Basically, I want to left-align some elements, but it seems I can't.

For example, I tried to left align the label in the modal like:

```
.remodal label {
   text-align: left !important;
}
```

but it didn't work? I took away `text-align: center;` in the wrapper, but that caused the modal to not be centered anymore?

Comment: It appears to work here - http://jsfiddle.net/fekyek9q/

Comment: @JoshCrozier, Oops, this does work, but for some reason <label> doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/j4wnov5z/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [..] for some reason `<label>` doesn't work

It's because the label element is inline by default. Thus, its width is determined by its content, in this case the text. If the width of the element is determined by the text, the text won't appear to be centered.

You could change the `display` of the `label` element to `block`. In doing so, it will have a width of `100%` and the text will be aligned to the left.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnqnyakp/)

```
.remodal label {
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target the `H1` in the modal try adding a rule like this to the CSS

```
.remodal-wrapper .remodal h1 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

I have updated your fiddle **here** - http://jsfiddle.net/aqobvdou/

Comment: can you see my updated fiddle? I'm trying to left-align a label, but it doesn't work?